# How do i make different words (in column A1, A25, A37) automatically show a value (in column B1, B25, B37)

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

Can someone please explain how to do this with different words:

I have two columns (A&B) and about 40 rows in excel. I want to put in different words, say - Paper in A1, Chair in A2, Glass in A3,and have values (say 25, 33, 47) show automatically in B1, B2, B3. [I know IF(A1="Paper",25,"") helps address this for row A1].

But, how can i pre-set the excel doc, for multiple words, such that when someone types - PAPER - in line A22, it automatically shows the value (25) in B22, or Glass in A29 with value (47) showing automatically in B29 . Can you kindly explain how to do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: List all possible words and associated values in a separate table and use `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Step 1 in [asking a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) is researching on your own. In this case, I think the phrase you were missing was "lookup table" or, as cybernetic.nomad mentioned, the name of a helpful formula. I personally prefer `XLOOKUP` but it's only available for Office 365 so `VLOOKUP` is more universal. Try a web search with some of those key phrases and see how far you can get on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).

Here is the formula in the sample.

**=IF(A4<>"",(VLOOKUP(A4,$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)),"")**

Just change A4 to other cell like A5, A6 and so on.

[image]